# Does $V\rightarrow W$ isomorphism map a $T:V\rightarrow V$ eigenvector to an $S:W\rightarrow W$ eigenvector?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-space-isomorphism

How would go about proving the following lemma?

> **Lemma:**
> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$, $\alpha:V \rightarrow W$ be an isomorphism, and $T:V \rightarrow V, S:W \rightarrow W$ be $\mathbb{F}$ linear maps. Then $v_1,...,v_n $ is an $\mathbb{F}$ basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ $\iff$
> $\alpha(v_1),...,\alpha(v_n) $ is an $\mathbb{F}$ basis of $W$ consisting of eigenvectors of $S$.

It is clear to me that $\alpha(v_1),...,\alpha(v_n)$ is a basis on $W$. However, I'm stuck on trying to show they are also eigenvectors.

I am attempting to use this as a lemma to prove a theorem covered in my lin algebra class:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T:V \rightarrow V $ be $ \mathbb{C}$-linear. Then $T:V \rightarrow V$ is diagonalizable $\iff \forall \lambda \in \sigma(T)$, ${\rm a.mult}(\lambda) = {\rm g.mult}(\lambda)$.

In the proof given by my professor, he assumes that $V = \mathbb{C}^n$.

Edit: This lemma is obviously wrong as helpfully pointed out by @Drew Brady.

Comment: Have you tried unpacking the definitions of these things: basis, eigenvector, isomorphism, linear map, vector space?

Comment: Hint: $w \in W$ if and only if $\alpha(v) =w$ for some $v \in V$, and $\alpha$ is linear...

Comment: I assume a.mult(λ) and g.mult(λ) are the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of λ respectively?

Comment: @C-RAM Yes, that's right.

Comment: As stated, by the way, the result is false. Take for instance $V = W = \mathbb{R}^n$. The identity map is an isomorphism. You seem to be claiming that the eigenvectors of every map are then the same? Are you sure you didn't drop a condition on $S$?

Comment: The problem is false if there is no relationship between $S, T, \alpha$.  Make explicit what that relationship is, and you will likely have a way to show what you want.

Comment: @DrewBrady Ok, thanks for pointing that out. 

This was my professor's suggested way of generalizing the fact that: Given $\mathbb{C}$ vector space V,  $\mathbb{C}$  linear $T:V \rightarrow V$.  For any $\mathbb{C}$ basis B: $[T]_{BB}$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ T is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the additional condition that $S = \alpha \circ T \circ \alpha^{-1}$, the result holds immediately, since
$$
S (\alpha v) = \alpha \circ Tv  = \alpha( \lambda v) = \lambda \alpha(v), 
$$
for any eigenvector-value pair $(\lambda, v)$ of $T$.